# How can I get Angular Universal to Compile Typescript for Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal

I'm trying to add Angular Universal to my Angular Firebase app. I've been following along with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wij2-gyG12E). But needed to make some changes in order to get it to work with cloud functions.

I have added an additional block of config to the "apps" array in angular-cli.config

```
// .angular-cli.config.json - "apps" [
{
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "serviceWorker": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles/styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
}
```

Next I have also added an additional file called tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

I then created an extra app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule, //  <-- needed for state transfer
    ModuleMapLoaderModule // <-- needed for lazy-loaded routes,
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Like the above video, the code gets transpiled into a dist folder for a browser app and server app. Although I have decided to avoid using webpack to create the server.js file and instead decided to add this to my cloud functions directly as typescript.

```
ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false
```

creates..

```
  dist/browser
  dist/server
```

Instead of server.js I've moved the code to cloud functions.js. However importing my server bundle from dist/server/main.bundle.js will cause the firebase deploy process to Error.

```
// cloud functions code above...

// Causes Error: -> const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./../../dist/server/main.bundle');

// more cloud functions code below..
```

The Error I recieve is:

```
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
project_root/node_modules/angular2-markdown/markdown/markdown.component.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Component, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

- I believe my cloud functions is only using node 6.
- The dist/server/main.bundle.js requires a node_module that uses es6 import syntax.

  dist/server/main.bundle.js -> require("angular2-markdown.. -> markdown.component.js:1 -> import <-- { Component,
- I've already tried asking the functions tsconfig.json to bring the output to es5, but I don't think it can manipulate the node_module .js dependencies to be a lower js. (The node_modules are 1 folder higher than the node_modules in the functions folder - (The dist folder is also 1 level higher above the functions folder))

functions/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5", // <--- Trying to es5 the output
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types-overwrite"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

- Is it possible to get firebase cloud functions to upgrade the node version to use the import syntax like Node 10.5?
- If not is there a way I can just edit my tsconfig to just get everything to transpile to es5?

### Update:

I've created an example github project to download and test the function deployment.

Link: https://github.com/Jonathan002/firebase-cloud-functions-node-6-import-statement-broken/blob/master/README.md

I have also tried to bundle everything as webpack_require to transpile the node_modules to be inlined with the bundle instead of being required using webpack, but have gotten the error:

> TypeError: o.initStandalone is not a function

I believe it comes from a firebase node_module being depended on, but I haven't been able to confirm this. (This error only appears on my own project I'm working on and it was hard to determine exactly what node_module to include in the example project to get these same error results with webpack).

Shown below though is the webpack config I used in functions:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib')
  },
  mode: 'none',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ]
  },
};
```

When in the functions folder, you can generate the bundled code using:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js --colors --progress
```

and removing the predeploy code with firebase's typescript functions in firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      // remove this..
      // -> "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      // -> "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using firbase tools you can create a ts version of the functions/index file during init.

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools

$ firebase init
```

In setup options, choose the ts option for the functions directory rather than js.